# how can I make sure the header cookie is passed on a post method in frisby.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-headers, session-cookies

I'm running tests on my api via frisby.js. When I login a user, I'm setting a header cookie from the response like this

```
.after(function(err, res, body){
  header: { content-type: 'application/json',
            Cookie: res.headers['set-cookie']
          ...}
```

Then in my following tests I write

```
frisby.create('test with cookie')
  .get('http://myapi/',{ headers: header})
```

This works fine, but when I do a post request

frisby.create('test  update email')
      .post('http://myapi/user/update', {
         email: 'newEmail@test.com', 
         headers: header
       })

I look at my console from the server, and the header is coming across as

```
{ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'host': config.baseDomain,
    'content-length': '269',
    'connection': 'keep-alive'
}
```

I thought maybe frisby was checking that the applied header was of the correct type, and updating the header without the Cookie, so I created a separate `postHeader` as

```
var postHeader = { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'host': config.baseDomain,
    'content-length': '269',
    'connection': 'keep-alive'
};
```

and appended the cookie to the post header and sent that through, but that doesn't work either. 
Any way I can get the cookie sent in a post header?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding:

```
.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

so something like:

`frisby.create('test update email')
.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.post('http://myapi/user/update', { email: 'newEmail@test.com'}, {json: true})
.expectStatus(200)
.toss();`